# Setting up AS3 for Heroku; collectstatic error for sendgrid

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, sendgrid

I'm attempting to setup Amazon S3 to use for static and media files on my first Django app on Heroku. The process has gone fairly smooth, but when running ./manage.py collectstatic to copy my static files to the AS3 bucket, I receive the following error:

```
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
  import settings
  File "/Users/me/djangoprojects/project/project/settings.py", line 165, in <module>
  EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
  File "/Users/me/djangoprojects/env/bin/../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key)
  KeyError: 'SENDGRID_USERNAME'
```

The settings for sendgrid have worked thus far for deployment:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I'm unsure of what the problem is as the files are not being copied to the AS3 bucket due to this error. Any insight or experience greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable environment variables during compilation.  Check out [the heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) (scroll down to the section about "Config Vars During Build").

*For the Lazy:*

```
heroku labs:enable user_env_compile -a myapp
```

Comment: Okay, this sounded like the problem. I ran that command and I'm still getting the error when trying to collectstatic. Should something else also be set? I've read through the docs and nothing appears to solve the problem. Should I push a new version to Heroku before trying again>

Comment: I pushed the revised master to Heroku and I'm still getting the same error. Truly perplexed.

Comment: Two things you might want to try: 1) `print os.environ` before the code that's causing the problem to see if the env variables are actually set.  2) use `os.environ.get` or `os.getenv` which default to None if the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an identical error deploying a Django app with Sendgrid to a Heroku review app. Our configuration was to spin up a review app whenever a new PR was opened on GitHub.

The issue turned out to be that Sendgrid's configuration in app.json was added to a pre-existing PR, which didn't trigger the generation of a new app. For Heroku review apps at least, add-ons are only generated the first time the app is deployed. As a result, the Heroku review app didn't have the Sendgrid add-on and was failing.

The solution was to check out another branch, push up to GitHub, and have Heroku generate a new review app from scratch.